# how embed jenkins pipeline in DSL script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dsl

I have a jenkins pipeline with user input.
I want to convert this in jenkins DSL to create jobs for each branch. For now I manually edit it, any pointers ?

Comment: Do you mean Job DSL? Why not use a Multibranch Pipeline if you want a job per branch?

Comment: I have jenkins pipeline made for single branch, For now I manually edit it and commit in git on another branch. Means I create jobs manually / branch